# Ambiguous because multiple kinds of members with this name exist in interface

Tags: vb.net, interface, primavera

this is the Interface:

```
Namespace IBasBS100
    Public Interface IBasBSMoedas <DispId(0)> <Obsolete("This method is obsolete. Use Actualiza(BasBE100.BasBEMoeda objMoeda, ref string strAvisos) instead.", False)>
        Sub Actualiza(objMoeda As BasBEMoeda, Optional strAvisos As String = "")
        <DispId(18)>
        Sub Actualiza(objMoeda As BasBEMoeda, ByRef strAvisos As String)
        <DispId(2)>
```

when i try to call the function that is not depracated it gives me the ambiguous error message:

```
   Dim avisos As String
   Dim bsmoedas As IBasBSMoedas = MotorPRI.Base.Moedas
   bsmoedas.Actualiza(m, avisos)
```

I think its calling the depracated method.
Is there any way that i could explicitly call the non depracated method "Actualiza(objMoeda As BasBEMoeda, ByRef strAvisos As String)"?

PS: I can not change the interface, it's an external Library

Answer (score 0):

I can only assume that the interface code was written in C# because that VB code won't compile. In VB, you don't explicitly state when passing an argument by reference, so the there's no way to differentiate between those two methods when calling one in VB code. In C#, you specify the `ref` or `out` keyword when passing an argument by reference, so there is no ambiguity in which overload you are calling, so it's allowed.

In short, you cannot call that interface method in VB. You can implement the interface in a class in VB and use a different name for one of the methods but you'd still have to call it through the class, not the interface. If you want to be able to use that interface then you're going to have to do it in C# code. Perhaps write a library in C# for the code that uses that interface and then consume that in your VB app.

I guess the other alternative to do it in VB would be to do so via Reflection. Far from ideal but I don't see another way.

Comment: Note that the interface is not legal to declare in VB; if you try, you get BC30300 and BC30345 errors for invalid overloads (differing only by optional parameters and differing only by parameters declared `ByRef` or `ByVal`).  I'm a little surprised C# allows it without warnings, other things that are legal C# but pose problems for VB will get warnings about violating the common language specification.

Comment: @Craig, I did note that it's not legal in VB, in the first sentence. Maybe you thought I was talking about the code using the interface rather than the interface itself. It shouldn't really be a surprise that C# allows it because the issue that exists in VB, i.e. that you cannot distinguish between the two overloads when calling, doesn't exist in C#. When calling those two overloads in C#, one requires the `ref`/`out` keyword and one forbids it. There's no way to mix the two up.

Comment: Oops, you're right, I did miss that.  My surprise isn't that it's legal in C#, merely that it compiles without warnings.  There are other things that are legal in C# but which will still produce warnings (e.g. members differing by case) because they won't work in other CLI langauges.  Admittedly, members differing only by case is much easier to get wrong in C#.

Comment: @Craig, yeah, that's a fair call. C# thinking only about itself. Typical! I guess this mustn't violate the CLS, although maybe it should.

Answer (score 0):

Primavera v10 funtions and VisualBasic aren't compatible with each other. Some may work, most won't. I would recommend changing to C# since this is the "supported" language of primavera.